# php returning primary key values from array

Tags: php, arrays

First i am sorry and please be gentle, i am just learning php and i sat down to code my basic cms just for practice but i am stuck.

i have a site settings table what contains the following

```
option           | option_value        | setting
site_name        | My site name        | general
site_description | My site description | general
site_keywords    | My site keywords    | general
```

I am doing the following select

```
"$results = SELECT FROM settings WHERE setting VALUES general"
```

My foreach loop

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
         {

            var_dump($result);
         }
```

I am getting back the following results from my foreach loop

```
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(16) "site_description"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site description "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(13) "site_keywords"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(14) "My site keywords "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(9) "site_name"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site name"
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
```

My question is is there any way to return the results like this

```
  ["option"]=>
  string(16) "site_description"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site description "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"

  ["option"]=>
  string(13) "site_keywords"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(14) "My site keywords "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"

  ["option"]=>
  string(9) "site_name"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site name"
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
```

So remove the array(3) index and join them? sorry because my english. maybe this is not the correct word for it, i was searching a lot on the net but did not find any solution.

Could someone please help out?

**Edit**

So as i said

foreach ($results as $result) 
     {

```
    var_dump($result);
}
```

I am getting back the following results from my foreach loop

```
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(16) "site_description"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site description "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(13) "site_keywords"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(14) "My site keywords "
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(9) "site_name"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site name"
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
```

So i will try to explain, because i will need to pass the results variable

so when i loop this way

```
 foreach ($results as $result ) 
    {
      var_dump($result['site_name']) ;
        }
```

so when i add site_name index in want to show that index option values, but if i do it this way i get **Undefined index: site_name**

Comment: No because in the examble you want you have multiples lines with same key, wich is not possible (option => site_description, option => site_name...)

Comment: instead of using mysql_fetch_array use mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: can you give an example of the outcome you want? What exactly do you need the array result to look like?

Comment: @user3058333, better yet use the `mysqli_` functions or PDO. The `mysql_` are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not. You can join them but you wouldn't have the result you say you want because you would have three elements with the same key. How would you acces the second elements option? Not possible.

Questionable if it is desireable.

I advise you to rethink why you would want that. Maybe the problem you think you have is solveable without getting such an array.

If what you want (as described in the comments) is an array holding the option_value for each option, what you can do is rearrange your array first.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
  $newArray[ $result['option'] ] = $result['option_value'];
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

**EDIT**: Reading your Edit thou, it seems your Problem is that you do not know how to access your array data.

You have this array:

```
array(3) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(9) "site_name"
  ["option_value"]=>
  string(17) "My site name"
  ["setting"]=>
  string(7) "general"
}
```

And you try to acces it this way:

```
var_dump($result['site_name']);
```

But 'site_name' is a value, stored in your array under the key 'option'.

So what do you expect to be the content of `$result['site_name']`?
If you want to get "My site name" you have to call `$result['option_value']` on the array holding `'site_name'`.
My solution above does rearrange your array to give you the acces you want, thou you say that is not what you want.
What is it that you want?

Comment: what im trying to achive is var_dump($result); if i pass the index like var_dump($result['site_name']); it will return the actual option_value

Comment: Thanks for your help, but never mind this is not what i want, thank you for your time

Comment: @WebStudent i think you are way off track.

Comment: @WebStudent i wrote an EDIt to my Answer since i think you did not at all understand how associative arrays work.